# How to read a .properties (java standart) in Javascript-React app (react-redux-webpack)?

Tags: javascript, java, maven, webpack, properties-file

I have a build.properties file, which is used by Maven for build purposes. I would like to use the same file and read from it in my front-end application (React-Redux-Webpack). I will provide more info if needed. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**SOLUTION**
I have reached a solution using an npm module called [properties-reader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/properties-reader).

1. Import the module (on the server side, in the webpack config) using 
   `const PropertiesReader = require('properties-reader');`

   ---
2. Read the .properties file again on the server side, in the same file as step #1 (in my case the file is called build.properties)
   `const appProperties = PropertiesReader('./build.properties')._properties;`

   ---
3. Declare the appProperties in the **externals section** of Webpack 
   `externals: {
               'appProperties': JSON.stringify(appProperties)
           },`

   ---
4. Just import the appProperties in any of your client .js files like
    
   `var appProperties = require('appProperties')` and use it freely

Example of my build.properties structure:
`warFilename=customer
 api_endpoint=xxx.xx.xx.xx
 version=1.19`

I am open for discussion. If you have any suggestions, I would be glad find an even better solution.